# Hibernate persist same object, same table in multiple databases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We are in the process of migrating database from one DB to another and we can not afford downtime for the application. So we want to write the same entity during this process and once we migrate, we can remove the source.  We are using hibernate for the application. Is there any way that hibernate can write the same entity in multiple schemas with same table structure ? . Also it should be transactional across these two DBs

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 Sessions, each Session with one DB Connection, then when you save a bean you call the `session.save()` from both Sessions.

Example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setName('FooName');
foo.setType('FooType');

session1.save(foo);
session2.save(foo);
```

You can wrap it in a `Service` so you can treat with a `@Transactional` and avoid saving in one DB and not on the other.

Comment: We have child entities, collections and sub-Childs as well. It will become harder when you try to persist the objects as sometimes the child entities might not exist in the second DB. So I am looking for a framework to do this or any easy way

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with persistence unit then it will work great for you. You can work with multiple data-sources (i mean, database connections) defining persistence unit. See the documentation of spring persistence unit and persistence context.

I hope it will help you what you trying to achieve.